# C# Call a file from a button click?

Tags: c#

I have a `Form` and a `Class: Form1` & `Timer`

In Form1 I have a button that looks like this

```
public void browseSoundToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    dialog1.Title = "Browse to find sound file to play";
    dialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
    dialog1.Filter = "Wav Files (*.wav)|*.wav";
    dialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    dialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    //PlaySound(dialog1.FileName, new System.IntPtr(), PlaySoundFlags.SND_SYNC);             
}
```

In Timer.cs I have an `Event` that looks like this:

```
public void alert_sound(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Alert Sound ding ding ding");

    //PlaySound(dialog1.FileName, new System.IntPtr(), Form1.PlaySoundFlags.SND_SYNC);
    alert_timer.Stop();
}
```

The problem is that in Timer.cs it says that dialog1 does not exist in the current context. How do I call dialog 1 from `Form1` into my `Timer` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, dialog1 needs to be declared at the module level.  You declared it within the browseSoundToolStripMenuItem_Click() method, so dialog1 only has scope for that method.

Move this line:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
```

to the top of the form.

Comment: Now I get Form1.dialog1 is inaccessible due to its protection level. Is that because it defaults to private? `public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();` This is what the top of my form looks like now

Comment: Yes.  Change it to public.

Answer (score 2):

You have created the dialog1 variable in a [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) local to the browseSoundToolStripMenuItem_Click event method. In order to access it from a different event you need to create it at the class level. Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    OpenFileDialog dialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();


    public void browseSoundToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dialog1.Title = "Browse to find sound file to play";
        dialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        dialog1.Filter = "Wav Files (*.wav)|*.wav";
        dialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        dialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        //PlaySound(dialog1.FileName, new System.IntPtr(), PlaySoundFlags.SND_SYNC);             
    }

    public void alert_sound(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Alert Sound ding ding ding");

        //PlaySound(dialog1.FileName, new System.IntPtr(), Form1.PlaySoundFlags.SND_SYNC);
    alert_timer.Stop();
    }

}
```

Comment: I see, I thought making the `browseSoundToolStripMenuItem_Click` method public would avoid the local scope issue. I have made it a class level variable now however in `alert_sound()` dialog1 is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: Really? If dialog1 is declared in the same class as alert_sound() it shouldn't matter if either are declared public or private. This is because the access modifier (the public, protected or private keyword) only applies to code accessing the variable/method from outside the class scope.

Answer (score 1):

your going to have to store the filename in a variable that can be called by the other method.

```
string filename = dialog1.Filename;
```

Possible to use the filename variable as a class level variable, but that is a suggestion as I don't know anything about your class and its layout.